# SyncFusion datagrid crashes "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream" when datagrid contains images

Tags: .net, maui, syncfusion, syncfusion-blazor-sfgrid

**SyncFusion datagrid** crashes **"System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream"** when swiping through the **datagrid (containing images)** left and right on a mobile screen.

This is the code for assigning the ItemSource to the datagrid. 'FieldVisitItems' is assigned to the ItemSource of the datagrid. I am inserting images in the datagrid and the images are taken from a stream. Is the culprit in the else block where if the image base64 string is empty, I am assigning a null stream. But the datagrid appears in this way as well on the mobile screen, but swiping left right causes it to throw the exception.

```
            FieldVisitReport obj = new();
        obj.SlNo = FieldVisitItems.Count() + 1;
        obj.AgentName = v.AgentName;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.Image1))
        {
            Stream s = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(v.Image1));
            obj.Image1 = ImageSource.FromStream(() => s);
        }
        else
            obj.Image1 = ImageSource.FromStream(() => null);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.Image2))
        {
            Stream s = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(v.Image2));
            obj.Image2 = ImageSource.FromStream(() => s);
        }
        else
            obj.Image2 = ImageSource.FromStream(() => null);

        obj.ClientCategory = v.ClientCategory;
        obj.ClientPartyName = v.ClientPartyName;
        obj.ClientPhone = v.ClientPhone;
        obj.TrackingStatus = v.TrackingStatus;
        obj.Datetime = v.DateNTimeUTC.AddHours(5).AddMinutes(30).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

        FieldVisitItems.Add(obj);
```

The Xaml:

```
            <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
            <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn HeaderText="Sl No" MappingName="SlNo" MinimumWidth="30"/>
            <syncfusion:DataGridImageColumn HeaderText="Product Photo" Aspect="Fill"
                                    MappingName="Image1" MinimumWidth="150">
            </syncfusion:DataGridImageColumn>
            <syncfusion:DataGridImageColumn HeaderText="Competitor Photo" Aspect="Fill"
                                    MappingName="Image2" MinimumWidth="150">
            </syncfusion:DataGridImageColumn>
            <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn HeaderText="Agent Name" MappingName="AgentName" MinimumWidth="150"/>
            <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn HeaderText="Client Category" MappingName="ClientCategory" MinimumWidth="150"/>
            <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn HeaderText="Client Name" MappingName="ClientPartyName" MinimumWidth="150"/>
            <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn HeaderText="Client Phone" MappingName="ClientPhone" MinimumWidth="150"/>
            <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn HeaderText="Date" MappingName="Datetime" MinimumWidth="150"/>
            <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn HeaderText="Tracking Status" MappingName="TrackingStatus" MinimumWidth="150"/>
        </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: My apologies. I edited the question and replaced the images with codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [ImageSource.FromStream doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.imagesource.fromstream?view=net-maui-6.0), there is a Remark saying *"The delegate provided to stream must return a new stream on every invocation."*.

That means the function passed to `ImageSource.FromStream` must do `new MemoryStream` every time it is called.

The error message implies that when you swipe, it calls the ImageSource again. I infer that the stream got closed after the first time it was used, so now it needs a new stream.

Try:

```cs
var temp = Convert.FromBase64String(v.Image2);

obj.Image2 = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    new MemoryStream(temp);
```

Or:

```cs
obj.Image2 = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(v.Image2))
);
```

Comment: Ok, but using new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(v.Image2)) is returning System.Exception: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.' exception. I am using Realm db in my application bdw.

Comment: That is progress. The FIRST code snippet should avoid that, by accessing `v.Image2` before thread gets changed. If it does not, then add `.ToString()` at the end of that line.

Comment: Seems working now, but without .ToString(). I am doubting how .ToString() can be applied here? since temp is expected to be a byte[] array. Converting it to string will throw error in the ImageSource.FromStream() method. Am I wrong somewhere? Thanks so much for the candid answer bdw.

Comment: ok, I'll remove  `.ToString()` from answer. I did not know what type it was.